# Hi, please because output is wrong apache-poi excel java

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

The code

```
public @ResponseBody byte[] generate(HttpServletResponse response) {

response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {

  File excelFile = new File();

  List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

  Column column = new Column();
  column.setHeader("Header 1");

  List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
  values.add("1.1");
  values.add("1.2");
  values.add("1.3");
  values.add("1.4");

  column.setValues(values);
  columns.add(column);

  column = new Column();
  column.setHeader("Header 2");

  values = new ArrayList<>();
  values.add("2.1");
  values.add("2.2");
  values.add("2.3");
  values.add("2.4");
  values.add("2.5");

  column.setValues(values);
  columns.add(column);

  column = new Column();
  column.setHeader("Header 3");

  values = new ArrayList<>();
  values.add("3.1");
  values.add("3.2");
  values.add("3.3");
  values.add("3.4");
  values.add("3.5");
  values.add("3.6");

  column.setValues(values);
  columns.add(column);

  excelFile.setColumns(columns);
  excelFile.setName("customers");

  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
      "attachment; filename=\"" + excelFile.getName() + ".xlsx\"");

  workbook.getCreationHelper();


  // Row for Header
  Sheet mySheet = workbook.createSheet(excelFile.getName());

  Row headerRow = mySheet.createRow(0);

  int cellCounter = 0;
  for (Column header : excelFile.getColumns()) {

    Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(cellCounter++);
    cell.setCellValue(header.getHeader());

  }


  int cellnum = 0;

  for (Column colum : excelFile.getColumns()) {

    int rownum = 1;

    for (String value : colum.getValues()) {

      Row row = mySheet.createRow(rownum++);

      Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
      cell.setCellValue(value);

      System.out.println("y: " + rownum + ", x: " + cellnum + ", value: " + value
          + ", Column Index: " + cell.getColumnIndex() + ", Row Index: " + cell.getRowIndex()
          + ", cell value: " + cell.getStringCellValue());

    }

    cellnum++;

  }

  workbook.write(out);
  InputStream byt = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

  return IOUtils.toByteArray(byt);

} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("(generate) IOException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    workbook.close();
    out.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("(generate) IOException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


return null;
}
```

the console output

y: 2, x: 0, value: 1.1, Column Index: 0, Row Index: 1, cell value: 1.1
y: 3, x: 0, value: 1.2, Column Index: 0, Row Index: 2, cell value: 1.2
y: 4, x: 0, value: 1.3, Column Index: 0, Row Index: 3, cell value: 1.3
y: 5, x: 0, value: 1.4, Column Index: 0, Row Index: 4, cell value: 1.4
y: 2, x: 1, value: 2.1, Column Index: 1, Row Index: 1, cell value: 2.1
y: 3, x: 1, value: 2.2, Column Index: 1, Row Index: 2, cell value: 2.2
y: 4, x: 1, value: 2.3, Column Index: 1, Row Index: 3, cell value: 2.3
y: 5, x: 1, value: 2.4, Column Index: 1, Row Index: 4, cell value: 2.4
y: 6, x: 1, value: 2.5, Column Index: 1, Row Index: 5, cell value: 2.5
y: 2, x: 2, value: 3.1, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 1, cell value: 3.1
y: 3, x: 2, value: 3.2, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 2, cell value: 3.2
y: 4, x: 2, value: 3.3, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 3, cell value: 3.3
y: 5, x: 2, value: 3.4, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 4, cell value: 3.4
y: 6, x: 2, value: 3.5, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 5, cell value: 3.5

y: 7, x: 2, value: 3.6, Column Index: 2, Row Index: 6, cell value: 3.6

but the file output is

Header 1    Header 2    Header 3

```
                    3.1
                    3.2
                    3.3
                    3.4
                    3.5
                    3.6
```

[output_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZTL8.png)

I can't understand why the first two columns are empty

I appreciate any help
The complete code

https://github.com/micha3lvega/FileManager
......

Answer (score 1):

Because every time you create a new row, previous row(s) is going to be ovrewritten.

Therefore, for column **Header 2**, you create a new row for each element in values, it will overwitten those rows created for column **Header 1**. And for **Header 3**, you create a new row for each element in values, it will overwitten those rows created for column **Header 2**.

And if you try to print the values of column **Header 1** and **Header 2** outside the for-loop, you are supposed to received `NullPointerException`.

According to your data structure, you can create a map to **reuse** the `Row`object rather than **create** a new one every time.

The sample code is shown as follows:

```
Map<String, Row> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Column colum : excelFile.getColumns()) {
    int rownum = 1;
    for (String value : colum.getValues()) {
        Row row;
        if (rowMap.containsKey("Row" + String.valueOf(rownum))) {
            row = rowMap.get("Row" + String.valueOf(rownum));
        } else {
            row = mySheet.createRow(rownum);
            rowMap.put("Row" + String.valueOf(rownum), row);
        }
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
        cell.setCellValue(value);

        System.out.println("y: " + rownum + ", x: " + cellnum + ", value: " + value
            + ", Column Index: " + cell.getColumnIndex() + ", Row Index: " + cell.getRowIndex()
            + ", cell value: " + cell.getStringCellValue());

        rownum++;
    }

    cellnum++;
}
```

Comment: @Michael Vega Hi, if my post solved the problem, please mark it as answer, thanks!